# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 removes carriage returns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 removing carriage returns from my data? Here is an example. If I email the returned value or copy and paste it into Notepad, all the carriage returns are removed. How can I keep them in? This doesn't happen in the 2014 version.

```
Declare @crlf char(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
Declare @mytable table(mytext varchar(100))
Declare @myinfo varchar(100)

SET @myinfo = 'This' + @crlf + 'is' + @crlf + 'foobar'

INSERT @mytable 
VALUES(@myinfo)

SELECT mytext 
FROM @mytable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "see" for sure what is going on, display the hex representation of the text. e.g.:

```
Declare @crlf char(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
Declare @mytable table(mytext varchar(100))
Declare @myinfo varchar(100)

SET @myinfo = 'This' + @crlf + 'is' + @crlf + 'foobar'

select CONVERT(varbinary(200), @myinfo)  as HexRepresentationBefore

INSERT @mytable 
VALUES(@myinfo)

SELECT mytext, CONVERT(varbinary(200), mytext)  as HexRepresentationAfter 
FROM @mytable
```

This shows both HexRepresentationBefore and HexRepresentationAfter as:

`0x546869730D0A69730D0A666F6F626172`

You can see the carriage return (hex 0D) and line feed (hex 0A) are indeed in the text.

Also, if you are using SSMS: if you are using the "Results to Grid" option, try using the "Results to Text" option. The carriage return and line feed may be more obvious when the varchar is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It does not remove it, it just doesn't show it in Results window.

You can get the length of string, it's still 16 characters. Or use substring to check.

Also:

```
SELECT @myinfo = mytext FROM @mytable
PRINT @myinfo
```